# Reuse a format specifier in C

Tags: c, dataformat

Is there a way to reuse a format specifier in C? I would like to use the same specifier for the next 20 outputs, is there an easier way than to write the specifier 20 times? v

In Fortran I can do this by writing 20 in front of the specifier, so (20F10.0) would be the same as (F10.0 F10.0 F10.0...). Is there something similar in C?

Comment: Ye olde copy/paste. Or, build the format string in a loop then use it.

Comment: No but you can call printf 20 times.

Comment: Short answer: no.  There are ways you could achieve this (two are shown in this question's answers so far), but anything "automatic" you could possibly do is going to be more complicated, more confusing, harder to write, and potentially buggier than just saying what you mean: `"%10.0f %10.0f %10.0f %10.0f %10.0f %10.0f %10.0f %10.0f %10.0f %10.0f %10.0f %10.0f %10.0f %10.0f %10.0f %10.0f %10.0f %10.0f %10.0f %10.0f"`.  (It took me less than 10 seconds to construct that, and it'll take you less, because you can copy and paste mine. :-) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the risk of your preprocessor macros looking like a snake with a severe stutter and your future self wondering why on earth you've done something like this, you could (ab)use the fact that string constants can be concatenated...

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define REPEAT5(s) s s s s s 
#define REPEAT4(s) s s s s
#define REPEAT20(s) REPEAT4(REPEAT5(s))

int main() {
    printf(REPEAT20("%d "), 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20);
}
```

If you run this [on Godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/197bnhPjM) you can see the format string was correctly expanded to

```
.asciz  "%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d "
```

Comment: I wonder if a printf helper method could be a wiser way to address that. Something like `printf(printf_expand("%{20}d %s %{2}04X \n"), ...)`. The helper method would only parse the format string to expand `{}` specifier and is ready-to-use for fprintf/sprintf/etc.. Pros for that would be a wider range of specifiers translations, cons would be that it requires machine code while macros don't.

Comment: A helper would require memory allocation (and a subsequent free) or not be re-entrant (since it'd have to involve a statically allocated chunk of memory).

Answer (score 1):

```
int x;
for(x=0;x<20;x++)
printf("%d", x);




It's just a diagram. In the 
body of the for loop, you 
can independently determine 
what exactly printf ( )will print.
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```c
char *n_format(char *format, size_t n, char delimiter)
{
    char *result;
    int  index = 0;
    size_t len;

    if (!format)
        return (NULL);
    len = strlen(format);
    if (!(result = malloc(len * n + n)))
        return (NULL);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        strcpy(result + index, format);
        index += len;
        result[index++] = delimiter;
    }
    result[index - 1] = '\0';
    return (result);
}
```

Usage:

```c
int main()
{
    char *string;
    string = n_format("%.5f", 5, ' ');
    printf("|%s|\n", string);
    // output: |%.5f %.5f %.5f %.5f %.5f|
    free(string);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: You're forgetting to free the format string returned by `n_format`. That's a memory leak :)

Comment: Also, there's no need to `strlen` within the loop; `format`'s length can't change in the loop.

Comment: true, i was just being a bit lazy with this, will fix now